# LaTeX equivalent of \str_if_eq:nnTF for property list keys?

Tags: l3prop

Here is a pure l3 code: I create a property list with 2 entries for keys `a` and `b`.
Then I loop over the entries and break for key `a` typesetting 'YES'.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \myProp
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \myProp {
  a=A,
  b=B,
}
\prop_map_inline:Nn \myProp {
  \str_if_eq:nnTF{#1}{a}
    {\prop_map_break:n {YES}}
    {NO}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

One can define new prop related commands to use higher LaTeX syntax instead.
The `\str_if_eq:nnTF` can be replaced by `\ifthenelse{\equal{...}{...}}{...}{...}` but that is not working here: the loop never breaks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \myProp
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \myProp {
  a=A,
  b=B,
}
\prop_map_inline:Nn \myProp {
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{a}}
    {\prop_map_break:n {YES}}
    {NO}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Property keys seem to be very special because testing values does break the loop:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \myProp
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \myProp {
  a=A,
  b=B,
}
\prop_map_inline:Nn \myProp {
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{A}}
    {\prop_map_break:n {YES}}
    {NO}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

How would I break when the key is `a` with only LaTeX code for testing ?

Comment: keys are strings so you would need `\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\tl_to_str:n{a}}}`.  But it looks very odd to use ifthen here. Why don't you stick to expl3 tools?

Comment: There is nothing that `ifthen` does (not expandably) that cannot be done with expandable `expl3` functions.

Comment: For good reasons, I really need to stick to LaTeX syntax. Adding a LaTeX layer over l3prop is quite easy. But for the test part, does it exist a LaTeX equivalent of \tl_to_str:n ?

Comment: The equivalent of `\tl_to_str:n` in e-TeX is `\detokenize`. But you didn't give any of the “good reasons”. :-)

Comment: \tl_to_str:n is \detokenize.

Comment: ifthenelse is possibly useful for very simple in-document uses to get some branching behaviour but I'd never use it in code, certainly not in expl3 code as there are far far better conditional macros available. Even at the time it was slow and non-expandable to fit with a pre-existing latex2.09 package syntax.

Comment: if you want a latex-document compatible name that does what `\str_if_eq:nnTF` does, use `\let\zzz\str_if_eq:nnTF` then use `\zzz{..}{..}{yes}{no}`